# Rails 3 - :remote => true for DIV or SPAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a word in DIV and if I will move cursor on the DIV, I need to display another DIV with another informations.

Is possible to add **:remote => true** to the next elements except **form** and **link_to**?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of the HTML in question?

Comment: I have something like that: `<div id="id_of_div>HERE!</div>` and if I will go with cursor on the word **HERE!**, so I am calling the event `mouseover` for displaying this div: `<div>This is the text displayed after by mouseover event</div>`. But to this **div** I need to get some information from database. And I don't know, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now this is not implemented, only inputs (buttons and submits), links and forms are applied. 
See the [sources](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)

But you can create your own addition to this behavior in application.js or elsewhere for divs, spans etc.

Comment: Ok, is a bit damage. I have to build my own solving, thanks for information.